# Что случиться если задача встанет в дедлок?

Tags: c#, асинхронность, task, tpl, async-await

Что случится если задача в неожидаемом асинхронном методе встанет в дедлок? Я просто навсегда потеряю 1 поток из пула? Например `_ = CallDeadLockAsync();`

Comment: Могут быть также потеряны ресурсы, использовавшиеся внутри.